# unknown conversion type character2

Tags: c

**When I want to print the 60 **Fibonacci** number  (it's long long number) with %lld conversion character ** ,**

it gives warning "unknow conversion type l" ,So I find that use %Id solve 
the warning in codeblocks c language
but what is the meaning of %Id ?

Comment: lower case for L

Comment: it's %lld  to represent long long int in c

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking here. If you realise that `%lld` is the format specifier for a `long long int` variable, then what is the problem? Please read the [help] pages and, if possible, edit your question to explain exactly what your problem is. Perhaps you could also fix the formatting and include a [mcve] to illustrate the issue.

Comment: %ld is for long. long long with %lld can be used with C99+, maybe you're using an older standard

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a mistake in your code
I write a programme  to check

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i, n;
long t1 = 0, t2 = 1, nextTerm;

printf("Enter the number of terms: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

printf("Fibonacci Series: ");

for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
{
    printf("%ld, ", t1);
    nextTerm = t1 + t2;
    t1 = t2;
    t2 = nextTerm;
}
return 0;
}
```

the answer is

```
60
Enter the number of terms: Fibonacci Series: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 39088169, 63245986, 102334155, 165580141, 267914296, 433494437, 701408733, 1134903170, 1836311903, 2971215073, 4807526976, 7778742049, 12586269025, 20365011074, 32951280099, 53316291173, 86267571272, 139583862445, 225851433717, 365435296162, 591286729879, 956722026041,
```

the value be 956722026041

if you change the

```
printf("%ld, ", t1);
```

to

```
printf("%lld, ", t1);
```

it work and the value is 956722026041

the deferent between %ld and %lld

%ld print for long

%lld print for long long

```
long n ;
printf("%ld",n);
long long nn;
printf("%lld",nn);
```